# Making leading apostrophe set in sql server work properly in excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, excel-2007

My problem is pretty weird, at least I think so.

If you write in Excel cell e.g. '4, it doesn't show the leading apostrophe. It's useful when you want to show something as text, not as number or date.

In my SQL Server code, I set some column names to ['1], ['2], ['3] etc.
In these columns I store numbers I want to make chart from, so that ['1], ['2], ['3] etc. are names of chart series (I want them to be visible as 1, 2, 3 on my chart legend).

Yet, when I copy these column names from SQL Server to Excel, it doesn't show them in standard Excel way (i.e., as text - 1, 2, 3). It shows them as they are, i.e., '1, '2, '3).

I can fix this if I replace all ' with ' (erm..). But replace all is not a very good solution for me. I would prefer a way to set SQL Server code somehow to make Excel recognize leading apostrophes the usual way it does. Do you know any way? Maybe it has something to do with character encoding?

Comment: are you talking about copying data with headers from a query result window?

Comment: Yes, from the result window.

Comment: set sql server column names to [1], [2],[3] - format the target excel column as text and you're done !?

Comment: No, I'm not, unfortunately. That way, Excel will not detect my 1, 2, 3 as series names and will use them as values. Setting that manually for 50+ series is pretty bad.

Comment: Then, it copies into Excel without that space - as a number